# DynamoDb Put Method not recognizing ExpectedAttributeValue() for column_2 - how to fix?

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use ExpectedAttributeValue() in Put method of map.

```
     public void saveToDynamoDb(TablePojo tableObj)
    {
         try 
           {
             map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> conditions = new HashMap<>(); 
             conditions.put("column_1",new ExpectedAttributeValue(false)); 
             conditions.put("column_2",new ExpectedAttributeValue(false)); 
          DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpr = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
          saveExpr.setExpected(conditions);
    dynamoDbMapper.save(tableObj,saveExpr)
          } 
          
          catch(ConditionFailedException e) 
          { //some message }
    }
```

So ExpectedAttributeValue is working for column_1 but not column_2. For column_2 it is still accepting the duplicate values. Also column_1 is annotated with @DynamoDBHashKey and column_2 is @DynamoDBAttribute.

what am I missing

Comment: Please share your full code, not just 1 line

Comment: @LeeHannigan I want column_2 to not accept duplicate values and for that I am using ExpectedAttributeValue(false) ..but still in my dynamoDB it is accepting duplicate values in column_2.. while when tried to add duplicate values in column_1 its throwing exception which is expected

Comment: Again, please share the entire code.

Comment: edited code snippet

Comment: Update to  AWS SDK for Java V2 and use the Enhanced Client. The AWS SDK V1 is not recommended to use anymore

Comment: ExpectedAttributeValue can only be used with key of table nad not with normal attributes. In my case column_2 is one column but not primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are checking if the attribute value is false, where in reality you want exists to be false.

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> conditions = new HashMap<>();
conditions.put("column_1",new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(false));
conditions.put("column_2",new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(false));

DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpr = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
saveExpr.setExpected(conditions);

dynamoDbMapper.save(tableObj,saveExpr);
```

Comment: Nope...didnt work